# Can't run an exe file on Ubuntu using Wine - JRE error

Tags: ubuntu, java, wine

I am trying to run an "exe" file on Linux using Ubunto through Wine. When I run it through the terminal I get this error:

```
This application requires a Java Runtime Environment 1.8.0(32 bit).
```

Wine has referred me to an Oracle link and although I followed the instructions and downloaded the JRE, it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to execute it in the WINE environment, you need to install the Windows implementation of the JRE *into* your WINE environment.  The executable that thinks it's running in Windows has no idea which (if any) JREs are installed on the host itself.

More to the point, why are you running a Java application in WINE? The whole point of Java is that it's OS-agnostic.  You may be able to get your hands on e. g. a `.jar` file to execute directly on your Linux host.

Comment: Hi! I'm aware java can run on any OS platform.
I have a school cyber project in which I have to conceal the source code from the user that is going to run the file. if I keep the jar file, it will be easy to access those files. 

thank you for your fast answer. can you specify more how to install it into the wine environment?

Comment: 1. You download JRE for Windows 2. You run it under Wine.

Answer (score 0):

You might possibly need to make sure that the default version of Java your system uses is the one that your installation of Wine requires, because you may have several versions of Java installed and your system might not be using the right one by default.
https://www.xmodulo.com/change-default-java-version-linux.html
Hope this helps.